# Pattern behind redux sagas

Tags: design-patterns, redux-saga

I've looking for a while the Redux-Saga github repo trying to understand the pattern behind the generator-effects library.

Could someone explain me, the real pattern behind the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern behind redux saga is Communicating Sequential Processes ( CSP ), is the way GO, ClojureScript and many languages manage concurrency.